# sed/awk make lines starting with lower characters be merged to previous line

Tags: text-editor, sed, awk

**Here is what I have**

```
This
is
a
sample
text

How
to
do
it
?
```

**I need the output to be:**

```
This is a sample text
How to do it ?
```

**In addition, how can I achieve the same with:**

```
This
is
a
sample
text
How
to
do
it
?
```

**How to append lines starting with non upper case characters to be appended each to previous line?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n([^A-Z])/ \1/g'
```

`:a` create a label `b`

`N` Search all the lines mashed together instead of searching line by line

`$!` if not the last line, `b` branch (go to) label `a` (skip the last line because the last line has a final newline)

`s` substitution

`\n\([^A-Z]\)` match a newline followed by anything not a capitalized letter. The `(` and `)` group together the anything not a capitalized letter.

`/ \1/'` replace our match with a space followed by group 1

`g` copy the hold buffer contents to the pattern space

Credit belongs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1004931) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697604/1004931) and [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/sed-part-2-data-structures-and-operators/).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works?

Comment: Ok. working on it.

Comment: **Error:** sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @Mina let met help Grimtech a little while he Googles up his explanation :-): his incantation uses extended regular expressions, otherwise his capturing parentheses would have needed backslash escaping. So sed must be invoked with -r.

Comment: @Grimtech you fixed this the other way round, by 'back-porting' the expression into an old-style regexp. Please revert and support the campaign for extended regexps. (Extended regexps have been POSIX standardized for ages and are supported by every grep, sed, awk, etc. out there. They are simpler, more consistent, and immensely more powerful. It's time to lay the old regexp syntax to rest.)

Comment: Out with the old, in with the new! I'm all for that, thank you for informing me.

Comment: This is very good! But perhaps something likes this should be added as well: **sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/ ([\?|\!|\.])/\1/g'**

Answer (score 3):

bash builtins is the quickest way :-)

```
declare -a A
mapfile -t A <inputFile
for line in "${A[@]}"
do
  if [ -n "${line}" ]
  then
     if [ "${line}" = "${line^}" ]
     then
         echo -en "\n${line} "
     else
         echo -n "${line} "
     fi      
 else 
    echo "" # newline, because input line was empty
  fi
done
```

Comment: I have a problem, In my actual file, there is no space between both sentences, so the output cames in one line! any help ?

Comment: @MinaMohsen: I have updated my answer. But please doesn't change the requirements in a question. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I think this doesn't apply on special characters, I mean the '?'. Ok, I will next time.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that some sentences may include Capitalized words as well, perhaps this might be the solution you're looking for:

```
sed -n '
1h
1!H
$ {
        g
        s/\n\n/<br>/g
        p
}
' | \
sed -n '
1h
1!H
$ {
        g
        s/\n/ /g
        p
}
' | \
sed -e 's/<br>/\n/g'
```

Comment: It works. But I have a problem, In my actual file, there is no space between both sentences, so the output cames in one line! any help ?

Answer (score 1):

How about a bash one-liner?

```
while read L; do case $L in [A-Z]*) echo ;; esac; echo -n "$L "; done; echo
```

Comment: Some lower case letters still exists at the beginning of some lines, dont know why!

Comment: @MinaMohsen Can you show me where this happens? I can't reproduce that. Your two examples above come out fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the first sample:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= file
```

with the second sample:

```
awk '/^[[:upper:]]/{print x}1' file | awk '{$1=$1}1' RS=
```